# Grafana Alert/AzureMonitor: Getting execution error while creating alert rules for graph in Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-monitoring, grafana-alerts, azure-monitor

**Description:**

I'm trying to create alert rule for graph(old) in grafana, but getting execution error.

**Grafana Configuration:**

- **Data Sources:** Azure Monitor
- **Dashboard:** AKS Monitor Container
- **Grafana** hosted in **Azure** as Docker Container
- **Notification Channel:** Microsoft Teams

**Alert Rule Config:**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

**Working State:**

- Configured notification channel(Type: Teams) is triggering perfectly.
- Grafana is working perfectly

**Tried Scenarios:**

- Deleted and recreated the whole Grafana Resource group in which a WebApps resource is there which is running Grafana dokcer image.
- Tried with adding grafana from Azure Marketplace.
- Searched a lot in google about this error but no luck.
- Checked multiple times the config of notification Channel, Grafana(in Azure portal), Alert rule.

So, if anyone know about this error, please let me know the solution.

(OR)

I missed some configuration for Alert/Notification. If it is, Let me know.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got the answer for this.

As per Grafana, it will not allow you to create an Alert rule, if you are using(or referring) any variable in query.

Also, I created an issue in [**github**](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/40249) and it's resolved. the fix can be seen in grafana 8.3.0